# Accessing KSEG2 addresses in GDB

Tags: c++, c, gdb, embedded, embedded-linux

We have a core file from an executable (N32 ABI, MIPS64 Rel2 Arch). From an embedded device where we have wired TLB's to use some of the KSEG2 space as well.
When the core file is loaded in GDB it throws the following error even thought GDB seems to have loaded the sections correctly (from "maintanence info section" output).

(gdb) maint info sec
...
    0xe0000000->0xe8000000 at 0x4100ff80: load5 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
...

(gdb) x 0xe0000000
0xe0000000:     Cannot access memory at address 0xe0000000

Any thoughts from anyone as to what I could be facing. Some assumption in GDB about the 2G KUSEG?.